# Allow a new user to access a section of a git server

Tags: linux, git, ssh, permissions

I've got this old tower that I use as a git server...I'm the only user, and honestly, it's more so I can just have access to my projects anywhere on any machine that's running Linux and with a copy of Vim.

However, now I've got someone else working on a project and I want them to be able to access a sub-directory only of a certain repo.

So, let's say the repo looks like this

```
└── repo
    ├── bar
    ├── cat
    ├── dog
    └── foo
```

The `repo` directory is where the `.git` is, but my partner and I are only working together on the `foo` directory.  So, how can I allow him access to only the `foo` directory?

Also, this server is running on Arch Linux but he'll be working using Windows.

What's the right way to do this?  Add a user and apply draconian restrictions to RW and R permissions?  How should I coordinate SSH keys, since he won't have access to something like `ssh-keygen`?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest creating multiple projects

Comment: I don't want to disintegrate all the history of these files...I'm very used to and fond of their file structure.

Comment: Separate the `foo` directory as a submodule, instructions (disregard the parts about pushing to GitHub): https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/